# Excel Concatenate Each Cell in Range

Tags: excel, excel-formula, concatenation

I have two formulas that find the range that I would like to concatenate.
One formula returns the cell address for the start of the Range for example:

```
 '[AM Track.xlsm]Raw Data'!$A$10`
```

The other formula returns the cell address for the end of the Range e.g.

```
 '[AM Track.xlsm]Raw Data'!$A$21`
```

How can I concatenate each cell in this range?

Comment: I believe that there is a new function in Excel 2016 which can do such things. @Jeeped once mentioned it to me. But I couldn't find it / get it to work. Maybe he/she has a solution to you problem.

Comment: @Ralph, I believe [textjoin()](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TEXTJOIN-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c) is what you are talking about. OP, if you don't have Excel 2016, you'll need a VBA function/UDF to pull this off.

Comment: Any suggestion on the VBA code?

Comment: This should get you started to create a loop: http://www.homeandlearn.org/excel_vba_for_loops.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comment about  TextJoin in Excel 2016 I found this:

```
Option Explicit
Function TEXTJOIN(delimiter As String, ignore_empty As String, ParamArray textn() As Variant) As String
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(textn) To UBound(textn) - 1
        If Len(textn(i)) = 0 Then
            If Not ignore_empty = True Then
                TEXTJOIN = TEXTJOIN & textn(i) & delimiter
            End If
        Else
            TEXTJOIN = TEXTJOIN & textn(i) & delimiter
        End If
    Next
    TEXTJOIN = TEXTJOIN & textn(UBound(textn))
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick VBA routine that mimics TextJoin in Excel 2016 and fits your needs would be:

```
Function textjoin(delimiter As String, ignoreEmpty As Boolean, startcell As Range, endcell As Range) As String
    Dim rngCell As Range

    For Each rngCell In Range(startcell, endcell).Cells
        If (ignoreEmpty And rngCell.Value <> "") Or Not ignoreEmpty Then
            If textjoin = "" Then textjoin = rngCell.Value Else textjoin = textjoin & delimiter & rngCell.Value
        End If
    Next rngCell
End Function
```

The difference between this and the built in Excel 2016 `textjoin()` formula is that the last two parameters are the start and end of the range (instead of just a single range like textjoin wants).

To use this, go to your VBE (Alt+F11). Create a new module in your workbook's VBAProject. Then paste this in.